# php return request URI from string

Tags: php, regex, url, uri, parse-url

I have a scenario where a user can enter a web address into a text field and I need to return the URI from it.

So a user could potentially enter addresses in the following state of fullness-

```
http://www.google.co.uk/contoller/function?stuff=thing
www.google.co.uk/controller/function?stuff=thing
google.co.uk/controller/function?stuff=thing
/controller/function?stuff=thing
controller/function?stuff=thing
```

From all of these examples I would need to return:

```
/controller/function?stuff=thing
```

(please note that that the domain could be anything, not just google!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    'http://www.google.co.uk/contoller/function?stuff=thing',
    'www.google.co.uk/controller/function?stuff=thing',
    'google.co.uk/controller/function?stuff=thing',
    '/controller/function?stuff=thing',
    'controller/function?stuff=thing',
);

foreach($arr as $a){
    print "/".preg_replace("@https?://.*?(/|$)|[^\s/]+\.[^\s/]+/|^/@", "", $a) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) for this purpose but this will need the URIs to be in a correct format.

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
var_dump( $parsed['path'] . $parsed['query'] );
```

Will get you the right result as long as the URI starts with `http://` (otherwise the domain will be parsed as path as well).

Comment: @andrewtweber Thanks! My server still runs 5.4.24 though ;)